# syscall.SO_REUSEPORT not available in net package

Tags: sockets, go, udp, so-reuseport

I want to open multiple UDP sockets bound to the same port( say 8888). The different sockets will be bound to different vrfs in the system.
What I understand is we need to set SO_REUSEPORT sockopts, but I don't see this available in [net](https://pkg.go.dev/net) package of Go.

Could someone help how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could set `SO_REUSEPORT` through [`unix.SetsockoptInt`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/unix#SetsockoptInt)

Sample codes

```golang
    lc := net.ListenConfig{
        Control: func(network, address string, c syscall.RawConn) error {
            var opErr error
            err := c.Control(func(fd uintptr) {
                opErr = unix.SetsockoptInt(int(fd), unix.SOL_SOCKET, unix.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
            })
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            return opErr
        },
    }

    lp, err := lc.ListenPacket(context.Background(), "udp", UDPADDR)

    conn := lp.(*net.UDPConn)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.
Any reason why syscall does not expose REUSEPORT settings?

Comment: @SaurabhSuman, here is one related issue https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26771. `The syscall package is frozen. We generally only add to it if the additions are needed elsewhere in the runtime or standard library.`